# Get admin and object id in a twig template (sonata admin)

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

How do i get the id of the admin and object in a twig template using sonata admin?

I have tried admin.getId() and object.getId() but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Its  unclear in which twig file you are trying to get the id in edit template/list template/show or any other please update your post with some code and also with complete details without these you will only have answers on basis of their guess

Comment: They should. Try listing properties and methods of thoose object in your twig with {{ dump(admin|keys) }}, {{ dump(object|keys) }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{ admin.id }} or {{ object.id }}?
```

Are you sure the admin and object variables are objects?

Look at this page: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html.

Comment: {{ admin.id }} will make Twig to look for getId, hasId, isId methods in admin object. I think it's ok to call methods in twig {{ object.method() }}. You can do it with attribute helper or in the regular way.

Comment: It's ok to call object methods in twig, yes. But if you have an array instead an object in twig asking property will work but calling methods won't.

Comment: `object.id` was the solution for me. Thank you.